# Find power series solution of $y^\prime=x^2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find power series solution of $y^\prime=x^2y$, determine the radius of convergence and identify the series solutions in terms of elementary functions.

So I started with $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$

then $y^\prime=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n-1}$

So rearranging and substituting the series I get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n-1}-x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0$$

then I changed the index on the first sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n-x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n- c_nx^{n+2}=0$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\big((n+1)c_{n+1}-c_nx^2\big)=0$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n-x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n- \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+2}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n- \sum_{n=2}^\infty c_{n-2}x^{n}=0$$
$$c_1+2c_2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^n- \sum_{n=2}^\infty c_{n-2}x^{n}=0$$
$$c_1+2c_2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty ((n+1) c_{n+1}-  c_{n-2})x^{n}=0$$
You can take it from here ?

As Tristan wrote in the comments you can deduce that:
$$
\begin{align}
c_1=&0 \\
c_2=&0 \\
(n+1) c_{n+1}=&  c_{n-2}
\end{align}
$$

You need to calculate some coefficients and try to find a pattern from the recurrence relation...

I ended with $$c_{3n}=\frac {c_0}{3^nn!}$$
$$\implies y(x)=c_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{3n}}{3^nn!}=c_0e^{x^3/3}$$

Comment: Do I need to simplify the sum more?

Comment: @AColoredReptile  I don't think so you can try to find the recurrence relation if it is possible..And also deduce that $c_1=c_2=0$

Comment: At this point, you can use the fact that a polynomial is only identically null iff all its coefficients are null. You get some new information (a new equation) for every $n$ you try

Comment: @AColoredReptile  I added some lines...

Comment: I computed some $c_3=\frac{c_0}{3}$, $c_4=\frac{c_1}{4}=0$, $c_5=\frac{c_2}{5}=0$, $c_6=\frac{c_3}{6}=\frac{c_0}{18}$. But I don't see much of a pattern there except that the only ones I don't know are $0$ will be $c_{3k}$

Comment: I added the recurrence formula @AColoredReptile

Comment: How do I find the radius of convergence? Sicne $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$ either $c_n$ or $c_{n+1}$ will be $0$.

Comment: I wrote the formula for the serie. It's an exponential @AColoredReptile  it's the radius of the solution that you are expected to find

Comment: @AColoredReptile you should find a radius that s infinity ...you can deduce that also because the radius of convergence of the exponential serie is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the result in the form$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n=0.$$If we define $c_{-1}:=c_{-2}:=0$,$$0=a_n:=(n+1)c_{n+1}-c_{n-2}.$$Since $c_0=1$, $c_n\ne0$ only when $3|n$. So define $b_n:=c_{3n}$, viz.$$b_0=0,\,b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{3(n+1)}.$$By induction, $b_n=\frac{1}{3^nn!}$.